# How to embeding raw H264 into MP4 ? (or MKV)

Tags: containers, embed, encode, mp4, h.264

I'm new to H264 and I need to embed some raw H264 into either MP4 or MKV.

I would be glad someone could refer me to a link or several that can explain how to do so.

(I've heard of MP4Box and ffmpeg but not of how exactly to use them for this purpose)

Comment: Did you attempt to read the documentation or examples of the libraries you mentioned?